# MySql group multiple timestamp queries in the same query

Tags: mysql, datetime, unix-timestamp

I am trying to write a MySQL function that will enable me to aggregate the amount of work done by staff members within set periods of time i.e. 1 day, 1 week, 1 month etc. Each item of work done generates 1 ID entry in the database.

the date of the entry is set as a timestamps.

my problem is that I am unclear how I will go about making several calls to the database to check how many entries were made during a set timestamp period.

**Below is the database table**

```
CREATE TABLE staffwork(
staff_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 


id_of_work_inserted MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
job_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

data_table VARCHAR (65) NOT NULL, 
entrytime int(11) NOT NULL, 

INDEX message (staff_id) 


);
```

**below is the query to place the data into the table, i.e the timestamp:**

```
INSERT INTO staffwork
 (staff_id, job_id, id_of_work_inserted, data_table,  entrytime )
VALUES ('$staff_id', '$job_id', '$id_of_job', '$data_table', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()) )";
```

**Below is my SQL function:**

function statsForEmployeesWork ($staff_id)
    {
        global $dbc;

```
$select = " SELECT 
                COUNT(job_id) AS totalWorkDone,
                COUNT(job_id) AS oneDaysWorkDone,
                COUNT(job_id) AS oneWeekWorkDone,
                COUNT(job_id) AS oneMonthWorkDone
                ";

$from   = " FROM 
            staffwork 
                ";

$where = " WHERE
                 staff_id = '$staff_id
               AND  
                  entrytime  >= now() - interval '1 day'     
               AND 
                  entrytime  >= now() - interval '1 week'
               AND
                  entrytime  >= now() - interval '1 month '";    

$query  = $select.$from. $where;

$result = mysqli_query ($dbc, $query)

    return $result ; 
}
```

I would really appreciate some help and advice on this.

Answer (score 0):

Your entrytime field is an int, meaning you can't use direct mysql date math, you'll end up doing stuff like

```
12345678 > '2013-11-14'
```

which is meaningless. Either convert your date ranges to ints, or convert your int field to a normal date:

```
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(entrytime) >= now() - interval 1 day
WHERE entrytime >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now() - interval 1 day)
```

Better yet, convert entrytime into an actual datetime field, and then your original query will work as expected.

Comment: hello Marc B, thank you so much for your reply. i am a bit confused why you did two WHERE cluases in the query. Can you please explain. thank you for your kind assistance

Comment: just examples of the two ways you could go. pretend they're "this way OR this way"

Answer (score 0):

In this clause

```
              entrytime  >= now() - interval '1 day'     
           AND 
              entrytime  >= now() - interval '1 week'
           AND
              entrytime  >= now() - interval '1 month
```

the first expression will discard all entries that are older then 1 day. So all of the values

```
            COUNT(job_id) AS totalWorkDone,
            COUNT(job_id) AS oneDaysWorkDone,
            COUNT(job_id) AS oneWeekWorkDone,
            COUNT(job_id) AS oneMonthWorkDone
```

will be the same.

You should split up your query to count each period separately:

**totalWorkDone:**

```
SELECT 
            COUNT(job_id) AS totalWorkDone

       FROM 
        staffwork 

       WHERE
             staff_id = $staff_id
```

**oneDaysWorkDone:**

```
SELECT 
            COUNT(job_id) AS oneDaysWorkDone

       FROM 
        staffwork 

       WHERE
             staff_id = $staff_id
           AND  
              entrytime  >= now() - interval 1 day
```

**oneWeekWorkDone:**

```
SELECT 
            COUNT(job_id) AS oneWeekWorkDone

       FROM 
        staffwork 

       WHERE
             staff_id = $staff_id
           AND  
              entrytime  >= now() - interval 1 week
```

**oneMonthWorkDone:**

```
SELECT 
            COUNT(job_id) AS oneMonthWorkDone

       FROM 
        staffwork 

       WHERE
             staff_id = $staff_id
           AND  
              entrytime  >= now() - interval 1 month
```

and of course convert `entrytime` into `datetime` field

Comment: Hello claustrofob, thank you for reply. i am unclear. do i then do 3 seperate SQL functions to obtain the data. 2. how do you mean convert entrytime into datetime field. how do i go about doing this